# Window form standard form size

Tags: c#, winforms, screen-resolution

I am using VS 2008, I have done some form designing, but I have a problem with a form not set in a proper manner.

Only half a form is displayed on the screen. My screen resolution is 1280*800 and I want to set my window form size to a fixed size for every screen resolution, how do I do that?

Comment: What do you want? To have the form shown full screen?

Comment: yes sir.. i want to show the form maximized with all the containt like panel and all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `System.Windows.Forms.Form.WindowState` property to `FormWindowState.Maximized` or use [Automatic Scaling in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605.aspx)